# Error establishing a database connection. While installing wordpress on Wamp Localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, wamp

I am installing wordpress on Wamp Localhost. I have even created new user with all priveleges.

I am installing it on MySQL and I have removed MariaDB.

Still the same error coming.

[image]

Comment: You have tested your connection with simple page connect?

Comment: @Ammad Can we have your wp-config.php file? Or simply test your database connection by creating a sample connection file and check if it is working?

Comment: Okay I m just checking.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini  Error is coming while connecting.

Comment: @ShashankShah  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\tutorialnew.php on line 20
( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\wamp64\www\tutorialnew.php on line 20

Comment: use mysqli not mysql! you wrong code for connection

Answer (score 0):

Try checking to see if the PHP MySQL extension module is being loaded:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If it's not there, add the following to the php.ini file:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

if it is there make sure its uncommented like below

if you see

```
;extension=php_mysql.dll
```

make it

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

Or another possibility to make sure if MySQL is installed you may check on the result of `phpinfo();` by searching `mysql`